# FORTRAN 90 separating digits in an integer

Tags: fortran90

Hej folks, I'm quite the beginner in programming but I read my share of stackoverflow pages, and googled a bit as well, still can't figure if the following is even possible in FORTRAN 90.

I'm trying to isolate the digits in an integer, to point where the hurdle is, consider the following idea :

INTEGER :: n, mult, add

READ *, n ! n = 8

mult = n*2 ! = 16

add = ??? ! where I want to add 1 + 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way, I trust that this will be obvious to anyone reading the code:

```
  INTEGER FUNCTION sum_digits(num)
    INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: num
    INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: digs
    INTEGER :: num_digits, ix, rem

    num_digits = FLOOR(LOG10(REAL(num))+1)
    ALLOCATE(digs(num_digits))

    rem = num
    DO ix = 1, num_digits
       digs(ix) = rem - (rem/10)*10  ! Take advantage of integer division
       rem = rem/10
    END DO

    sum_digits = SUM(digs)

  END FUNCTION sum_digits
```

I've subjected this to a quick series of obvious tests and it has passed all 4 of them.  If you find a case for which it doesn't work, fix it.  And if you want the array of digits returned, modify the function to return that. If you want it to work for negative integers too throw in `ABS()` at an appropriate place.

Answer (score 0):

one way to pull off the 'ith' place digit is:

```
 n/10**i-10*(n/10**(i+1))
```

so for your example:

```
      n-10*(n/10)  +   n/10-10*(n/100)
```